# Why didn't Darth Vader fly out to space in the end of Rogue One?

Tags: star-wars, darth-vader, rogue-one

We saw that Grievous flew out to space in Episode 3 when the windows cracked.

But why didn't Vader and his troops do the same thing at the end of Rogue One?

Comment: Related - http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/149080/why-was-darth-vaders-cape-fluttering-at-the-end-of-rogue-one?rq=1

Comment: [Magnetic boots](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Darth_Vader's_armor) for Vader possibly, *The boots soles also contained a ferromagnetic core which could be activated by Vader's mouth-operated controls to generate a strong magnetic field similar to that of zero-g spacesuits used by soldiers to cling to starship hulls...*

Comment: [Team Vader's blasting off agaaaaaaaain!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dKcZ8u5fbyw)

Comment: @Alistair86 - "*Boot soles contain a ferromagnetic core that can be activated with mouth-operated controls. The resulting electric charge generates a strong magnetic field*" - [Darth Vader: A 3D Reconstruction Log](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Darth_Vader:_A_3-D_Reconstruction_Log).

Comment: @Valorum Ah, I failed to check the source.. I did briefly look to see if Stormtroopers also had magnetic boots, but couldn't find anything.

Comment: From the title, I somehow thought this question was going to be, "Why didn't he jump out into space after the *Tantive IV*?"

Answer (score 17):

As has already been suggested, magnetic boots are a distinct possibility.

Another is that the hanger bay didn't actually depressurise into hard vacuum (which, incidentally is not a mutually exclusive possibility.) Energy barriers that allow solid objects to pass though but retain the atmosphere are well established in SW lore starting right from ANH. Indeed, they appear to be standard practice where hanger bays are concerned.

Yes, there's clearly quite a bit of "wind" causing his cape to flap about in an appropriately exciting and dramatic manner, but it's possible that may simply be due to the Tantive IV departing.
While it was in the bay it was taking up volume. When it left, that volume would become a void and cause a pressure differential with the rest of the ship.

The natural result would be air rushing down the corridor from other parts of the ship to fill said void and re-balance the air pressure, which is more or less what we saw.

Comment: +1 Nice explanation.  Of course, capes *always* look cooler blowing around than standing still.

Comment: In the hard vacuum of space,  retailing atmosphere sounds like a wise business venture.

Comment: @Kris You could add that explanation for cape fluttering as an answer to the other question. Neither of the answers there was accepted yet as the official answer.

Answer (score 6):

Within the Legends canon, we learn that Vader's boots have magnetised soles that will adhere him to a metal floor.

> Boot soles contain a ferromagnetic core that can be activated with mouth-operated controls. The resulting electric charge generates a strong magnetic field. Similar technology is used in zero-g spacesuits that make it possible for soldiers to cling to starship hulls.
>
> <sub><sup>[Darth Vader - A 3-D Reconstruction Log](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Darth_Vader:_A_3-D_Reconstruction_Log)</sup></sub>
>
> [image]

We see these used to good effect in [Star Wars: Empire: Volume One: Betrayal](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Empire:_Volume_One:_Betrayal)

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Simple answer: He used the force. No need for magnetic boots or anything complicated.

Comment: Force can't be used to levitate, at least in main canon.

Comment: @Gallifreyan It can in Rogue One, which this question is about...

Comment: Do you have some evidence for this?