# How was the Resistance able to rescue this character?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi

In *The Last Jedi,* after the opening battle, the Resistance makes a jump to hyperspace.  Shortly after exiting hyperspace (Spoilers follow),

> it is discovered that the First Order has somehow followed them, and another brief battle ensues.  This results the *Raddus's* bridge being destroyed, with many of the highest ranking leaders being blown out into space, killing all but one of them: General Leia.  She is able to use the Force to pull herself back to the ship, where she is able to re-enter the bridge and approaches a sealed door.  Here, we see that Poe, Finn, and Lieutenant Connix saw her coming, and they opened the door to let her in.

How were they able to open the door without being blown out into space?

Comment: We don't see it close but this is clearly an airlock *passage* with a door at the other end. One presumes that it closed before the other opened.

Comment: I’ve removed the character tags, this question was only _about_ one character, and leaving that one in would be an obvious spoiler.

Comment: Star Wars is never about things being scientifically correct.

Comment: Or making any logical narrative sense.

Comment: @Paulie_D airlock? Oh please. Who the hell installs an airlock between a bridge and a corridor? It was just a door. And we've seen people going in an out. It was a normal door which magically morphed for one shot.

Comment: I forgot about one thing. How the hell is she floating outside the bridge? I thought the Raddus was constantly accelerating at top engine load. If they weren't accelerating anymore, the momentum from being sucked out of the bridge would make her overtake Raddus and keep going, and if they were accelerating, eventually Raddus would leave her behind.

Comment: @Petersaber - You can use the Force to float, apparently.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In the official novelisation it's explicitly stated that **she entered an airlock.** She then used the Force to close the outer door and the crew then opened the inner door.

> *Even as her senses dimmed, her body rose toward the gaping maw of the
>   shattered bridge. **It slid through the wreckage and into the lock.
>   Leia’s fingers brushed the viewport, and the outer hatch closed.***
>
> ***Then the inner door opened,*** flooding the narrow space with light and
>   air and life. Faintly, as if from a great distance, she heard
>   contradictory commands and agonized questions surrounding her. The
>   Force was bright and spiky with fear.

[image]

Comment: “The Force was bright and spiky with fear.” Spiky? The Force was spiky? Man, that wording just sounds so stupid and silly. :/

Comment: @RedCaio "bright"? "spiky"? "FEAR" ?!

Answer (score 2):

A related answer is [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/82320/how-do-the-death-stars-retain-atmosphere-in-the-landing-bays). Most starship hangars in the films are open to vacuum, and covered by magnetic shields or force fields.

This isn't a definitive canon answer, but it seems reasonable to speculate that sort of shielding might be used in a reactive way in damage control. The last answer at that link (by Darth revan) references the game Old Republic and states that containment fields were effective against small breaches.

Comment: Do we have any reason to believe these fields/shields could be raised anywhere?

Comment: As I note, the link references the Star Wars game Old Republic.

Comment: Sure, but nothing suggests these could be spontaneously erected in random holes and breaks, otherwise what’s the point of a hull?

Comment: @Edlothiad: The point of a hull is so you can rely on the physical property of materials most of the time rather than projecting an expensive force field. Otherwise why not just have a ship made out of forcefields?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit That’s my point exactly, If they can be randomly erected why not have them everywhere?

Comment: @Edlothiad: I just told you why.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit you speculated as to the fact that they may be expensive to project, but if they can be projected everywhere anyways that doesn't sound like they'd be expensive. Making a hull useless, besides for the traditional "not falling through". Either way you've taken a rather insignificant analogy and made it the focus. When the point was about the fact that there's nothing to suggest these fields/shields can be projected anywhere.

Comment: @Edlothiad: Okay.